# Application of multidimensional Feynman-Kac theorem on some parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, markov-process

**Setting**: let us consider a vector $v=(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and a time horizon $[0,T]$ for $T>0$ such that for any $0\leq t\leq T$ we have the following partial differential equation with a terminal condition $\psi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ at time $T$:
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
&\partial_tu(t,x)+xy\partial_xu(t,x)+\frac{1}{2}\beta(t,x)\partial_{xx}u(t,x)=yu(t,x)+g(t,x,y)\\
&u(T,x)=\psi(x)
\end{aligned}\tag{1}
\end{align}
for some function $u:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

**Question**: *can we apply Feynman-Kac theorem to PDE $(1)$?*

**Proof**: let $v=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The multidimensional Feynman-Kac theorem is valid for a parabolic PDE on a unknown function $U:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with form:
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
&\partial_tU(t,v)
+\sum_i\alpha_i(t,v)\partial_iU(t,v)
+\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\sum_j\beta_{ij}(t,v)\partial_{ij}U(t,v)
=\gamma(t,v)U(t,v)+g(t,v)
\\
&U(T,v)=\psi(v)
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
\end{align}

Let us fix $v=(x,y)$ and set:
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_x(t,x,y)&=xy\\
\beta_{xx}(t,x,y)&=\beta(t,x)\\
\gamma(t,x,y)&=y\\
\psi(v)&=\psi(x)\\
\end{aligned}\tag{3}
\end{align}
as well as:
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_y(t,x,y)\partial_yU(t,x,y)&=0\\
\beta_{yy}(t,x,y)\partial_{yy}U(t,x,y)&=0\\
\beta_{xy}(t,x,y)\partial_{xy}U(t,x,y)&=0\\
\beta_{yx}(t,x,y)\partial_{yx}U(t,x,y)&=0\\
\end{aligned}\tag{4}
\end{align}

PDE $(2)$ combined with $(3)$ and $(4)$ yields PDE $(1)$, up to the point that in $(2)$ the unknown $U$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$, whereas in problem $(1)$ the function $u$ merely depends on $x$. However given:

1. the terminal condition function $\psi$ only depends on $x$;
2. condition $(4)$, which entails partial derivatives involving $y$ have null contribution,

can we actually conclude that $U(t,x,y)=u(t,x)$ that is $U$ does not depend on $y$? If so, is the Feynman-Kac theorem still applicable?